# UK marriage visitor visa with children traveling

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, children, weddings

Do I need to apply for a tourist visa for my children, who are US citizens, to enter the UK with me for the wedding if I have already been approved for a marriage visitor visa? Or are they covered by my marriage visitor visa as my dependents?

Comment: I think I've seen a duplicate of this question, but I don't see it now.  I am fairly sure that your children do not need a visa, but not entirely sure.

Comment: I am really confused because I remember when I was filling out the application, it clearly said dependents should apply separately. If anyone could help the confusion please.

Comment: I believe that means that they should apply separately *for whatever visa they might need.*  If they were from a non-visa-exempt country they would need a (separate) standard visitor visa to accompany you, but since they're from a visa-exempt country, they do not need a visa.

Answer (score 2):

In general even children need a visa. If they are under 18 they can be included in a parent's visa application, or they can apply separately. The fact that they are 'dependents" doesn't get them admitted without an application

However US citizens do not need a visa to visit the UK, assuming they will stay for less than six months and haven't been excluded for some reason. So there is no need to make a visa application for them. You (or they) present their US passports at immigration, answer the questions asked, and unless there is a problem they will be admitted.